# How to get raw xml as string from Element

Tags: python, xml, soap

I've the following code which parses an XML response and returns a list of Element objects representing products.

```
tree =  ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(raw_xml_response))
products = root.findall('//Product')
```

I now need to get the raw XML from each Product so I can store it in a DB.  It seems Element doesn't have a method to do this - what's the customary way to get the raw XML from each Product Element?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a top-level function called `tostring` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring)) that accepts an element, try

```
print([ET.tostring(product) for product in products])
```